# Variable is not expanded in a command with diff

Tags: zsh, variable

My shell is zsh. I tried these command on bash, which successed.

```bsh
ignore_files=(
    local
    \*.local.\*
    .bundle
    Gemfile.lock
    )
ignore_command=""
for f in "${ignore_files[@]}"; do
    ignore_command="$ignore_command -x $f"
done
echo $ignore_command 
# print: -x local -x *.local.* -x .bundle -x Gemfile.lock 

sudo diff -ruNd  $ignore_command <path a> <path-b> 
# failed: diff: extra operand '<path-b>'


echo sudo diff -ruNd  $ignore_command <path a> <path-b> 
# sudo diff -ruNd  -x local -x *.local.* -x .bundle -x Gemfile.lock <path a> <path-b>

eval diff -ruNd  $ignore_command <path a> <path-b> # success
```

It seems that the variable isn't expanded in that command. I want to know why and how to make it like bash without eval.

Comment: The fact that it works in `bash` is purely accidental. As soon as you add a name with a space in your array, or a pattern that matches a name in the current directory, it will stop working in `bash`. Don't combine separate array items into a single string. You don't even need to do that in pure `sh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A command is a list of arguments, you want to use an array to store those arguments here:

```
ignore_files=(
    local
    '*.local.*'
    .bundle
    Gemfile.lock
)
ignore_command=()
for f in "${ignore_files[@]}"; do
    ignore_command+=(-x "$f")
done
print -r -- "${(q+)ignore_command[@]}"
sudo diff -ruNd  "${ignore_command[@]}" <path a> <path-b>
```

You are probably being confused by the behaviour of Bourne-like shells where leaving a parameter expansion unquoted is a split+glob operator, so it turns a string/scalar variable into a list (or files matching patterns) *upon expansion*.

That misbehaviour was fixed by `zsh` and most other modern shells like `rc`, `es`, `fish`.

You could emulate that behaviour of the Bourne shells with `set -o shwordsplit -o globsubst`, but that would be going backward. Specifically, `globsubst` would be a problem in your case as `*.local.*` contains glob characters.

In `zsh`, if you want to split a variable or perform globbing upon its expansion, you have to ask it explicitly:

- `$=var`, splits `$var` on `$IFS` characters.
- `${(s:,:)var}` splits on specific strings (here `,`)
- `$~var`: performs globbing (or pattern matching depending on context) upon expansion (for instance if `$var` contains `*`, `$~var` in list context will expands to the list of files in the current directory like the Bourne shell's `$var`)
- `$=~var`: does both splitting and globbing so is like the `$var` of the Bourne shell.

In this particular case, you could also do:

```
sudo diff -ruNd  --exclude=$^ignore_files <path a> <path-b>
```

(where the `^` causes the array to expand like in `fish` or `rc` as `--exclude=element1` `--exclude=element2`... It actually enables the `rcexpandparam` option for that one expansion like `~` enables `globsubst` and `=` `shwordsplit`).